# How to change default Proxy HTTP endpoint in wso2esb

Tags: proxy, wso2, wso2-esb

I wish to change my URL of proxy service due enhanced application.
Previously my URL like differet than ESB default endpoint.
Now proxy providing this URL.

```
http://soccerhome:8280/services/Customer_Proxy
```

Where as my existing applications are running on some other endpoint's
like

```
 http://soccerhome:8280/Customer_Proxy
```

So they can't able to change there endpoint how would i remove the **service** part in above URL any way to do that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just provide a Service URL in your_proxy.

```
<parameter name="ServiceURI">Customer_Proxy</parameter>
```

Then You will get Your desire URL.

Answer (score 0):

Change parameter **servicePath** in *repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml*

Comment: I have removed the property but still its giving like that only.

Comment: If i keep it empty like    <parameter name="servicePath" locked="false"></parameter> its giving errror service path should not be empty so How Would i remove this

Answer (score 0):

Edit the repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml in dispatcher phase :

```
<phase name="Dispatch" class="org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase">
```

to add the following handle.

```
<handler name="CustomURIBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.CustomURIBasedDispatcher"/>
```

Now if you go ahead to edit the proxy service, you can add a service parameter as, 
serviceURI = Customer_Proxy

This will provide your desired URL.

Answer (score 0):

you should change axis2.xml file in repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml or create your service in proxy url

```
<parameter name="URL OF Service">CustomProxy</parameter>
```